# form.is_valid is not validating

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make register possible on the homepage (register box appears onclick), so I don't have a seperate URL to handle registration. I'm trying to send the form through `get_context_data`, however it's not working. Here's my code:

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()

    # login
    form = UserRegistrationForm(self.request.POST or None)
    context['form'] = form
    if form.is_valid(): 
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return context

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass
```

**base.html**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="registerBox">
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The fields show up but after submitting the form it doesn't create a User because my form.is_valid is False. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return a response from `get_context_data()`. Instead, do that in the `post()` method like this:

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()
        context['form'] = UserRegistrationForm()
        return context
```

Comment: Changed it to that but still getting a Method Not Allowed (POST): /home/
 "POST /home/ HTTP/1.1" 405 error. Any idea?

Comment: I actually changed how to do that. I don't think returning a response from `get_context_data` is correct. You should do that from `post` instead.

Comment: You're getting a method not allowed error because the `ListView` does not have a `post` method. So you'll need to add one like in the example. See [Classy CBV](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) for the available methods/attributes on `ListView`.

Comment: Tried that, submitted the form and got this error: ValueError: The view app.views.BoxesView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Did you use the `post` method or the `dispatch` method? I accidentally said dispatch at first...

Comment: Ok so I tried the post method just then and there's no error but it isnt creating a User. Any idea?

Comment: Is it redirecting? Also, the second parameter to [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) is email, not password. So pass password in as a kwarg, like this: `password=password`. Also, the `save` is unnecessary (`create_user` saves the User). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just used your new answer, it is redirecting but still not creating a new User.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Form expects to have `confirm_password` submitted, but that's not part of your html form.

Comment: Try printing `form.errors` and `form.non_field_errors` after the `if form.is_valid()` block, and see what errors it prints